# Where to put application so I can use them no matter working directory?

Tags: linux, terminal, directory, ngrok, bin

I installed ngrok and put it in the `/bin` folder. But I can only use the command `./ngrok` when I'm in the `/bin` directory. I'm pretty new to using Linux but I'm quite shure that `/bin` apps/command can be used everywhere. Anybody know where to put applications so I can use them no matter what's my current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

If `/bin` is in the `$PATH`, you can call it with `ngrok`, without specifying the current directory `./`.